# Return number of arguments function is called with?

Tags: javascript

How do I create a function that returns the number of argument/s it was called with.

**Examples:**

```
numArgs() ➞ 0

numArgs("foo") ➞ 1

numArgs("foo", "bar") ➞ 2

numArgs(true, false) ➞ 2

numArgs({}) ➞ 1
```

**My code**

```
function numArgs() {

}
```

Comment: `arguments.length` or use rest syntax and do the same thing, `numArgs = (...args) => args.length`

Comment: function numArgs(...var_args) { return var_args.length; } than call numArgs(5,1,3,6,7); it'll return no of argument. you can pass any no of argument to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use arguments.length as defined by MDN

```
function numArgs() { 
  return arguments.length;
}
```

as defined here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/length

Answer (score 1):

You can use the

```
function.length
```

or

```
arguments.length
```

hope this helps.